# Record from two devices, and failing to record from hardware device, ffmpeg

Tags: linux, usb, audio, ffmpeg

I realize that asking two questions at once is likely a breach of normal protocol, but since I think perhaps my two problems are related (and I only really need to fix the first one if the second isn't relevant), it seems the only sensible way forward to describe both at once.

What I actually want to achieve is to take two separate USB audio input devices, and record from them both simultaneously (synchronized, so separate files really does not seem to be a viable option).

One problem is that I'm not sure how I might express this request to ffmpeg, the docs are huge and it's very hard for a beginner to even know where to start looking. In some way, that's probably because I don't know what the concept names are, so the index entries don't call out to me.

Another problem is that in order to achieve this, I'm pretty sure I'll need to refer to the hardware devices directly (since `-f alsa -i pulse` can, I believe, only refer to the "currently selected" pulse device). Now, if I try to record from a single device, one of them works fineif I refer to it by the name `hw:2`. The other one, currently `hw:3` has an annoying tendency to report busy, but if I get past that, I always get an error: `cannot set sample format 0x10000 2 (Invalid argument) hw:3: Input/output error` However, if I attempt to record from it via pulse (that being the only change; select it as default input, and refer to it as `-i pulse`, instead of `-i hw:3` then it works (still singly, obviously) just fine.

Any pointers? Am I trying something impossible? What part of the ffmpeg docs should I be referring to?

EDIT: As my search continues, I'm wondering if this might be something for which I must understand "complex filtergraph", or possibly something that the "jack" system might handle. I haven't succeeded in really understanding either yet, but they seem like possible contenders?

EDIT (adding info):

Here's a selection of the commands and output that I've been trying to use, with comments inline, as usual `[...]` indicates I elided stuff that doesn't seem useful in helping understand:

```
toby@LinuxStudio:~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
[...]
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: 92HD99BXX Analog [92HD99BXX Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: CODEC [USB Audio CODEC], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 3: U192k [UMC404HD 192k], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

toby@LinuxStudio:~$ ffmpeg -f alsa -i hw:3 -sample_rate 48000 -channels 4 -channel_layout quad test.wav
[...]
[alsa @ 0x563b07aa6960] cannot set sample format 0x10000 2 (Invalid argument)
hw:3: Input/output error

toby@LinuxStudio:~$ ffmpeg -f alsa -i hw:2 -sample_rate 48000 -channels 2 -channel_layout quad test.wav
[...]
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, quad, s16, 3072 kb/s
[...]
Exiting normally, received signal 2.

toby@LinuxStudio:~$ ffmpeg -f alsa -i pulse -sample_rate 48000 -channels 4 -channel_layout quad test.wav
[...]
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, quad, s16, 3072 kb/s
Exiting normally, received signal 2.

toby@LinuxStudio:~$ ffmpeg -f alsa -i pulse -sample_rate 48000 -channels 4 -i hw:2 -sample_rate 48000 -channels 2 -channel_layout hexagonal test.wav
[...]
hw:2: Protocol not found
Did you mean file:hw:2?
```

So, in particular, notice that the command with `hw:2` works for two channels, the command with `hw:3` fails with "Invalid argument", the equivalent command works when referring to `pulse` instead of `hw:3` (and with the pulse default device set to `hw:3` using the `pavucontrol` so they should be the same target).

Also, my best guess on a format for grabbing from two inputs is clearly a syntax error, but I am guessing, so that's not a surprise!

Finally, I find that about nine times out of ten, if I try to use the `hw` format for accessing the four-channel device, ffmpeg rejects the effort with `cannot open audio device hw:2 (Device or resource busy)
hw:2: Input/output error` That always happens I use `pavucontrol` to select the device as default, but doesn't go away if I unselect it, and often happens even if the device was never default.

Comment: What is the full command that you're trying?

Comment: Edited to try to be more helpful. Notice I'm totally guessing on the multi-card input; I just have no clue where to start, and my attempt was pretty random :(

Comment: I'll further add that I think this: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation is trying to tell me something (there's a multi *file* input to 5.1 format example), but I'm failing to find the docs on how to use filter_complex and am hoping (unrealistically!) that ffmpeg might have a workable default!

Comment: The two hardware devices will have slightly different clocks, so if you want to do this for any extended period of time, you need resampling to keep it synchronized.

Comment: Uh oh @Dirkt, I understand the nature of the problem (I've seen things get out of sync with video). I might get lucky, as most of my material will be under ten minutes, but not all. Can you elaborate on "resampling"? Is this something that ffmpeg can do automatically, or will I have to open it in some manual tool (audacity?) and stretch things, as I've done with video?

Comment: @Dirkt, I tried adding simply "aresample" to the filter_complex, and that didn't work. It reports "Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 0 on filter Parsed_aresample_1" which I admit means nothing to me...

Comment: Resampling means "if I get 44100 samples from source A, and 44101 from source B, interpolate all samples from source B, yielding 44100 samples". I don't know `ffmpeg` well enough, so I don't know if it does resampling based on the actual drift - it would have to react to ALSA buffer overflows/underflows, or whatever ALSA uses to signal it. I know that Pulseaudio does resampling, and in theory also syncs, but I've heard that it doesn't always work as it should. I didn't try it myself.

Comment: Anyhow, it's something to check your recordings for - if they are still in sync at the end, fine. If not, you need to figure out something - e.g. if you don't get it to work automatically, you can still do it manually.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks dirkt, I can work with that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you set hw:3 as default device and then try the following,

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -sample_rate 48000 -channels 4 -i pulse -f alsa -sample_rate 48000 -channels 2 -i hw:2 -filter_complex amerge test.wav
```

Comment: This looks like it might work... Can't test properly right now, but will do so in the next few hours. Many thanks!

Comment: Yes, so grateful you could show me the simple version of filter_complex! I had really hoped it would have an easy mode, but couldn't get to first base finding it.